# How to determine the joint PDF given a graph?

Tags: probability-distributions

Given the following graph:

[image]

$$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \begin{cases} a &, x,y \in OABCDE \\ 0 &, \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

My solution:
$$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \begin{cases} a &, 0 \leq x \leq 2, 0 \leq y \leq 2 \\ 0 &, \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, You have described a square. $OABCDE$ is not a square.

$$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \begin{cases} a& ,0\le x \le 2 , \max(0, x-1) \le y \le \max(1, x) \\ 0 & \text{,otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Furthermore, we can find what is $a$.

First find the area of $OABCDE$, $a$ is its reciprocal.

Comment: To find a, could I also use the formula $\int_0^{2} \int_{max(0, x-1)}^{max(1,x)} a dydx = 1$? If so, how would I proceed to find the exact domain of the second integral?

Comment: Yup, you can use that, just that I think it's faster if you just view it as a geometry problem, you can shift some triangle around to form a rectangle to get the area quickly.

Comment: Thank you! I got a = 1/2 using the area. I have one more question: If I want to find the marginal PDF of X, on what domain to I integrate to find it? I mean I can't integrate on $max(0, x-1)$ and $max(1,x)$.